# C++ dynamic memory allocation of struct inside class via pointers is assigned nullptr "sometimes"

Tags: c++, heap-memory

I have a simple example. I have a class, inside of it I have a struct that includes a pointer of type double. Inside that class, using a function therein, I intend to allocate dynamic memory using pointers. Out of curiosity, why does when I compile sometimes (50% of the time I compile) these pointers are initialized to be null and sometimes not?

A minimally-working example starting with the header file could be:

```
class house{

    struct room{
        double *roomPtr;
    } roomObj;

    room *myRoom = &roomObj;

public:
    void startPainting();

private:
    void paintRoom();
};
```

As for my cpp file, then it may be summarized (via a minimal example, as above) as:

```
void house::paintRoom(){
    if (myRoom->roomPtr != nullptr){
        myRoom->roomPtr = new double[someNbr];
    }
    else{
        cout << "Allocation failed !" << endl;
    }
}
```

For convenience sake, consider that in this class the public function's job is to simply allocate the memory (never mind freeing for now) -- i.e.

```
void house::startPainting(){
    paintRoom();
}
```

Anyway, when compiling the main (by simply creating an object of the class and running the public function...), sometimes (almost every other time) I get "Allocation failed!" -- i.e. the pointer was null. Is this typical, or am I doing something wrong?

Also, I understand that I may instead of using the above approach to allocate memory, I can per se do the following without the additional pointer(s):

```
roomObj.roomPtr = new double[someNbr];
```

This always works, but then again I am just curious why the above doesn't always work. May you please shed some insight on my shortcoming(s) ?

Thanks !

Comment: Because you forgot to assign it to anything?

Comment: you mean roomPtr? But, do I need to assign it to a value/address before allocation? :/

Comment: only if you want it to have a certain value/address in it? Otherwise it could have any address in it. Which might or might not be NULL

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the pointer `roomPtr` to a default value, such as in class' constructor. The memory in these objects are initialized in an implementation-defined way, so you may randomly get it assigned to a null value but it is not guaranteed.

For example, this modification would be better and provide consistent behavior:

```
house::house() : roomObj(), myRoom(&roomObj) {
   myRoom->roomPtr = nullptr;
}
```

As a side note, it doesn't fully make sense to me why you have a second member variable that is just pointing to some memory within the same class when you have a separate member variable describing it.

Comment: wouldn't this mean that the pointer is always assigned null? How then will allocation occur...

Comment: also, as for why it doesn't make sense... it's just something I came up with to convey the inconvenience I think I have and try to understand why. In reality there are far more classes and member functions as well as variables in that struct.

Comment: In this case yes, but you could change that. For example, it could be `myRoom->roomPtr = new double[10];`. I was more emphasizing this constructor, which would be called each time a house object is created, would give consistent behavior than hoping it gets set to `nullptr`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is just the way it is. If I recall correctly, the standard was written this way to give implementations maximum flexibility when allocating memory for variables. For example, an implementation may want to maximize the speed of allocating these variables, so it may spend minimal additional time in assigning default values.

Comment: I would have created a dummy variable and assign the roomPtr to its address, but I have several pointers within this struct and I need to dynamically allocate memory in a contiguous way. If I define them to dummy double variables at start then they might not turn out to be contiguous (for memory performance purposes). I could be wrong. That's why I am asking here anw :-)

Comment: @Inquisitor101 "wouldn't this mean that the pointer is always assigned null? How then will allocation occur... " - maybe you should get rid of the `if(myRoom->roomPtr != nullptr)` and then allocation will occur even if it is null? The only reason allocation doesn't occur when it's null is because **you** told it not to!

Comment: @immibis I see what you are saying. Just to be clear though, from what I recall (I have been off of programming especially in C/C++ quite a while), one is still able to allocate memory even if the pointer is null? Then why do we see a similar if/else condition in codes still? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Inquisitor101 You definitely can allocate memory even if the pointer is null. Going back to your original code, usually one would test `myRoom->roomPtr == nullptr` to see if it is null and then allocate memory to be held by the pointer.

Comment: @Inquisitor101 You are definitely missing something about how pointers and/or memory allocation works, but I'm not sure exactly what you're missing. Someone would check whether a pointer is null because they want to know whether it's null...

Comment: DanielDay I think I got the confusion. @immibis , yup I agree. Anyhow, thank you. It always feels weird and messy whenever you take a (really) long time off of programming. Better look through basic tutorials then to freshen up :-)

Comment: @Inquisitor101 Often you set a pointer to null so you can remember whether or not you allocated memory, does that help? If it's null then you didn't allocate memory yet, if it's not null then you did. Of course that is only one particular use of null-ness.